# How to change viewBox to center an element in svg

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I have a svg map which contains a bunch of circles, on click on a circle I want to make the circle the center of the canvas. I am using **RaphaelJS** to work with svg.

I have tried `paper.setViewBox(width / 2 - cx, height / 2 - cy, width, height, true)`, where *cx* and *xy* are the coordinates of the selected circle in my svg file, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you share a working example?

Comment: I am already trying to find one myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculations look wrong to me.  I would expect it to be:

```
paper.setViewBox(cx - width / 2, cy - height / 2, width, height, true)
```

Comment: cx - (settings.vb.width / 2), cy - (settings.vb.height / 2)